# Set initial value for bootstrap checkbox button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm using the code below to set the middle checkbox to be true but it's not working. What am I missing?

For demo go to http://jsfiddle.net/5sq7v/

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox">Hello 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Hello 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox">Hello 3
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the 'active' class in the second label. Is this what you were looking for?

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox">Hello 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Hello 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox">Hello 3
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Bootstrap's bleeding-edge docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/2d1d5754f781f0f3fa1bc296c9e69da416043c4a/docs/_includes/js/buttons.html#L41):

> #### Pre-checked options need `.active`
>
> For pre-checked options, you must add the `.active` class to the `<input>`'s `<label>` yourself.